# Woocommerce redirect to different thank you pages on specific shipping method selectoin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to work on something new for displaying 2 different thank you pages for the woocommerce plugin. When a user has selected a different shipping method like local pickups I want to redirect them to different thank you pages after checkout.

I have added the following code but it doesn't works redirects to the default. What am I doing wrong

```
// Thank you page redirect
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woo_custom_redirect_after_purchase' );
function woo_custom_redirect_after_purchase() {
    global $wp;
    if ( is_checkout() && !empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( 'https://mywebsite.com/thank-you-page-1/' );
        exit;
    }
    elseif( $order->has_shipping_method('local_pickup:7') ) {
        wp_redirect( 'https://mywebsite.com/thank-you-page-2/' );
        exit;
    }
    elseif( $order->has_shipping_method('flat_rate:1') ) {
        wp_redirect( 'https://mywebsite.com/thank-you-page-3/' );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Not sure what's happening, might be I'm missing or doing something wrong.

Comment: When you say 'redirects to the default' do you mean it goes to `thank-you-page-1`?  Looking at your `if()` statements, the first one seems like it would always trigger, so the other two would never be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function, you don't define `$order`.  You need to get the $order Object before you can access any of the methods.  Since `$order` is not defined, the other cases `elseif` are never true.

```
// Thank you page redirect
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woo_custom_redirect_after_purchase' );
function woo_custom_redirect_after_purchase() {
    global $wp;
    // Get the order object
    $order = new WC_Order($wp->query_vars['order-received']);
    if ( is_checkout() && !empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( 'https://mywebsite.com/thank-you-page-1/' );
        exit;
    }
    elseif( $order->has_shipping_method('local_pickup:7') ) {
        wp_redirect( 'https://mywebsite.com/thank-you-page-2/' );
        exit;
    }
    elseif( $order->has_shipping_method('flat_rate:1') ) {
        wp_redirect( 'https://mywebsite.com/thank-you-page-3/' );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a redirect? I don't know exactly what you're up to, but maybe it is enough to display different content, depending on the shippment method? If so, you can edit the [thankyou.php](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-templates-checkout-thankyou.html) template.

First copy the file `plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/thankyou.php` to your theme directory `themes/(your-theme)/woocommerce/checkout/tankyou.php`. Here you can change the thankyou template, without losing the changes after a woocommerce update. ([Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/))

Now you can adjust the `thankyou.php` (inside your theme directory) and add your conditions at the right place:

```
if ( $order->has_shipping_method('local_pickup:7') ) {
    echo "thank you content 2";        
}
elseif ( $order->has_shipping_method('flat_rate:1') ) {
    include 'path-to/my-tankyou-content3-file.php';
}
```

Comment: It throws an error Uncaught Error: Call to a member function has_shipping_method() on null

Comment: Actually I have created a thank you page using elementor rather than hard coding most of the parts in it. So just wanted to get redirected. I have added the above code and tried using the `WC()->cart->has_shipping_method(` but still throws error  *Call to undefined method WC_Cart::has_shipping_method()*

Answer (score 0):

//Use this hook to target your thankyou page.

```
<?php

add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'your_function_name'); 

function your_function_name($order_get_id){

// Here comes your code

}
```

Comment: Its redirecting but i want to use different thank you pages depending on the selection of shipping methods as explained above.